# Should we frame whole packet ( headers , check sum, etc ) to use netmap?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

I red about netmap which allows user programmers to access packets in the user space, that means user applications can read / send network packets very quickly using this netamp.

netmap :
           http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/

Can any one who are very familiar with netamp, tell me should we create entire packet that we want to send out, or we using the stack features to send it out.

Edit : here is example on how to use this api
    https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netmap&sektion=4

```
     #include <net/netmap_user.h>
 void sender(void)
 {
 struct netmap_if *nifp;
 struct netmap_ring *ring;
 struct nmreq nmr;
 struct pollfd fds;

 fd = open("/dev/netmap", O_RDWR);
 bzero(&nmr, sizeof(nmr));
 strcpy(nmr.nr_name, "ix0");
 nmr.nm_version = NETMAP_API;
 ioctl(fd, NIOCREGIF, &nmr);
 p = mmap(0, nmr.nr_memsize, fd);
 nifp = NETMAP_IF(p, nmr.nr_offset);
 ring = NETMAP_TXRING(nifp, 0);
 fds.fd = fd;
 fds.events = POLLOUT;
 for (;;) {
     poll(&fds, 1, -1);
     while (!nm_ring_empty(ring)) {
     i = ring->cur;
     buf = NETMAP_BUF(ring, ring->slot[i].buf_index);

     // here they are saying to construct the packet

     ... prepare packet in buf ...
     ring->slot[i].len = ... packet length ...
     ring->head = ring->cur = nm_ring_next(ring, i);
     }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create entire packed, including ethernet, ip and tcp headers. Netmap completely bypasses kernel network stack, so you need to do all work yourself.